# Usage of “on" or “in” with “plan"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

When I am inquiring about an offer in store, there are some add-ons that are not included in the plan. Should I use ***on*** or ***in*** with "the plan", saying:

> Is there any free add-ons ***on/in*** this plan?

And in another situation,  like when I am telling someone that he will be included in my work or project plan.  Which should I choose,  telling him:

> You are ***in/on*** my plan?

If these two situation have different choice, is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to project documentation, "the plan" could refer to two things:

1. The document outlining the plan
2. The plan itself, in action

For example, a particular diet may be outlined in a document such as a book. You would speak of details being *in* a book, yet someone who was following it would be *on* the diet.

Likewise I believe you would speak of details being **in** a written plan (such as a project document), but once the plan was in effect you would speak of things being **on plan** to mean that you were still following the plan, or things were *going to plan*.

---

In your other example where "plan" is used to describe something like a mobile phone contract, you would almost certainly say "on" the plan if you were referring to anything inclusive in it:

> "Would I get inclusive text messages on this plan?"

But in your example you specifically talk about "add-ons", which by nature are *extra* to a plan. So if you were asking about anything *extra* that may be bundled if you took a plan, you might actually say:

> "Would I get any add-ons **with** this plan?"

Because the the add-ons are not part *of* the plan, but you might get them *as well*.

---

Your last question:

> "There is talk that Airbus could snatch even more market share **in** that deal. They have made a killing **on** the deal"

Refer to the first part of my answer. If you are referring to the plan as an entity in itself, either the document or the concept, then you would say something is *in* that plan. But once the plan is up and running then you are *on* that plan.

Comment: Thank you very much. What about my first question? When I ask the assistant in store about the deal, which one I should use? Like I asked 'Do you have any free add-ons on your deal or in your deal?'

Comment: Thank you so much for your answering up to my newest question. I can understand your first part answer, but when coming to my last one, Imho, it isn't a matter of the whether the deal has begun, the two sentences both describe a situation that happened during or after the deal.@Astralbee

Comment: @Young As my answer says, a "plan" is two things. If you are talking about the plan as an entity in itself, a document, or a concept, then a detail is either **in** that plan, or not, and that doesn't matter if it is in motion or not. Someone or something that is *using* that plan is **on** it.